# How to attach logged in user to Django exception error messages?

Tags: django

When I get an error exception email from my Django site it would be useful to see the User and/or UserProfile information for the currently logged in user.  How do I add this to the Django site exception error emails?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Django appends repr(request) at the end of the e-mail.  Using the default wsgi development server you can find the logged in user as

'LOGNAME': 'myuser',

This may be hidden in some e-mail clients as it is wrapped in angle brackets.

```
<WSGIRequest
GET:<QueryDict: {}>,
POST:<QueryDict: {}>,
...
'LOGNAME': 'myuser', 
...
wsgi.run_once': False,
'wsgi.url_scheme': 'http',
'wsgi.version': (1, 0)}>
```

Also, you can implement a custom middleware that implements the process_exception method:

process_exception(self, request, exception)

request is an HttpRequest object. exception is an Exception object raised by the view function.

Django calls process_exception() when a view raises an exception. process_exception() should return either None or an HttpResponse object. If it returns an HttpResponse object, the response will be returned to the browser. Otherwise, default exception handling kicks in.

Again, middleware are run in reverse order during the response phase, which includes process_exception. If an exception middleware return a response, the middleware classes above that middleware will not be called at all.

Comment: +1 for suggestion of middleware... in fact, we use this approach quite successfully.

Comment: This no longer works for at least Django 1.9 (older versions could be impacted as well).

Answer (score 4):

@jsamsa's answer doesn't appear to be true anymore due to changes in Django (at least I don't get a 'LOGNAME' field in error emails).

I am posting an alternative, to receive the full django html error page via email.  Details on that are here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/#django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler

and this [ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10863) helpfully points out that you can do this:

```
LOGGING['handlers']['mail_admins']['include_html'] = True
```

Comment: With `include_html` you indeed get pretty HTML emailed, but where can I find the username of the user that caused the error? At least I couldn't find it. `logname` isn't part of what I got mailed. Also, I'm sure the user was logged in since the page where the error was seen on is visible to logged in users only.

Answer (score 0):

From Django version 1.10 onwards, this is supported natively: see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.10/.

> Added request.user to the debug view.